# If $A \ge B$, $A_1 \ge B_1$, $A \ge A_1$, and $B \ge B_1$, is $A_1 B \ge A B_1 $?

Tags: calculus, inequality

We define $A$,$A_1$,$B$ and $B_1$ as $4$ positive values.
Suppose that $A \ge B$ and $A_1 \ge B_1$. Also, assume that  $A \ge A_1$  and  $B \ge B_1$.

Using the above, do you think that $A_1 B \ge  B_1 A$  ?

Comment: I forgot to put the equality.. Question edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosider $A = 2$, $B = 1$, $A_1 = 1$ and $B_1 = 0.75$. All your constraints hold. But still, $A_1B = 1\cdot 1 \geq 2\cdot 0.75 = AB_1$ is not true.

Comment: I am sorry.. I forgot to put the equality. Question edited!

Comment: I changed it to $B_1 = 0.75$, still not true...